# What are restrictions of the MPM algorithm and Push-relabel algorithm for max flow?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, restriction, max-flow, push-relabel

I am coding this and need to be aware of the restrictions for these two different algorithms:
1) Capacities have to be integer or not?
2) Graph has to be acyclic or not?

Can anyone give some hint?

Thanks